# Variable declare but not used inside the main function

Tags: go

If I use variable inside a function then Go gives error otherwise not please check 2 examples.

GIVES ERROR **n declared but not used**
https://play.golang.org/p/z-EktUDkNDz

```
  package main

  func main() {
    var n int
    n = 10
  }
```

NO Error when var declared outside the function https://play.golang.org/p/nFSEoktcE5e

```
  package main

  var n int

  func main() {
    n = 10
  }
```

Comment: To determine that the first version does not use `n` the compiler needs to check ony the function in which `n` is defined. This is simple. For the second version the compiler would have to check _all_ functions. This is complicated (and slow).

Answer (score 4):

That's as per the standard:

> Implementation restriction: A compiler may make it illegal to declare a variable inside a function body if the variable is never used.

Reference: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Variable_declarations

Please make a note that it states "**may make**". That means it's up to a particular compiler implementation. But in general it's better to assume it's not allowed.

And there is no such similar restriction for variables declared in a global scope.